# Can an array or function lvalue be converted to an rvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue

According to C++ Standard 2003:

```
An lvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to an rvalue.
```

What does it mean that array and function cannot be converted to rvalue?

Comment: I don't even know what an lvalue of a function or array type would look like, assuming it even exists.

Comment: @Neil: An lvalue of array type is simply an expression that designates an array object.  Given `int arr[20];`, the expression `arr` is an array lvalue.  (It's converted to a pointer in most, but not all, contexts.)

Comment: @KeithThompson CatPlusPlus's answer makes it all clear, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both function and array types are covered by later clauses (4.2, 4.3).

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N  T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to an rvalue
>   of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.
>
> (...)
>
> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to
>   the function.